# Is there a way to open DICOM files?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

I have done an RMI scan, and I wonder if it's possible to open DICOM files, to see it. Ubuntu recommended I install ImageJ, but that didn't decode it or whatever.

A friend of mine opened it with Photoshop and seems like it worked, but I need a program I can easily use on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

All available from Ubuntu software center:

- [dicomscope](http://dicom.offis.de/dscope.php.en). [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dicomscope.1.html).

  ```
  sudo apt install dicomscope
  ```

  > DICOMscope is a free DICOM viewer which can display uncompressed, monochrome DICOM images from all modalities and which supports monitor calibration according to DICOM part 14 as well as presentation states. DICOMscope offers a print client (DICOM Basic Grayscale Print Management) which also implements the optional Presentation LUT SOP Class. The development of this prototype was commissioned by the "Committee for the Advancement of DICOM" and demonstrated at the European Congress of Radiology ECR 1999. An enhanced version was developed for the "DICOM Display Consistency Demonstration" at RSNA InfoRAD 1999. The current release 3.5.1 has been demonstrated at ECR 2001 and contains numerous extensions, including a print server, support for encrypted DICOM communication, digital signatures and structured reporting.
- [ginkgo-cadx](http://ginkgo-cadx.com/en/).

  ```
  sudo apt install ginkgocadx
  ```

  > Ginkgo CADx is an advanced DICOM viewer and dicomizer (converts png, jpeg, bmp, pdf, tiff to DICOM).
- [aeskulap](http://aeskulap.nongnu.org/)

  ```
  sudo apt install aeskulap
  ```

  > Aeskulap is a medical image viewer.
  >   It is able to load a series of special images stored in the DICOM format for review. Additionally Aeskulap is able to query and fetch DICOM images from archive nodes (also called PACS) over the network.
  >   The goal of this project is to create a full open source replacement for commercially available DICOM viewers.
  >   Aeskulap is based on gtkmm, glademm and gconfmm and designed to run under Linux. Ports of these packages are available for different platforms. It should be quite easy to port Aeskulap to any platform were these packages are available.

Comment: I could view my x-rays with dicomscope and aeskulap. Maybe it's possible with ginkgo-cadx as well, but I need to try it again with that.

Comment: None of these worked on my dicom files. Perhaps they are no longer updated/maintained for latest formats? Unfortunately we may have to resort to wine+windows.exe applications (non-FOSS trial-ware, not a reasonable long term solution), or programmatically convert to (more common) standard image formats.

Comment: aeskulap worked fine with my DICOM files, circa 2019. Couldn't open them with Gimp, which surprised me.  Dicomscope didn't work, maybe my images are compressed.  I am talking Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, bionic, kernel is 5.0.0-25-generic.

Comment: Most of those didn't work for me, I get a blank screen. Seems like they are all based on dcmtk which needs a license to be able to deal with JPEG2000 compressed DICOM files. [source](https://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?p=9814#p9814)
I've tested [Weasis](https://github.com/nroduit/Weasis) and it worked for me with sample  JPEG2000 compressed files.

Comment: Aeskulap works well for me in 20.04 & 22.04.

Comment: [Aeskulap](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/aeskulap/aeskulap/) is 15 years old, judging from its source code.

Answer (score 38):

### [Weasis](https://nroduit.github.io/en/) (on [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.nroduit.Weasis))

From all viewers I tested, I liked Weasis the most.

It is cross-platform, has lots of features (measurement, 2D/3D view, etc.) and works just fine.

> Here are the main features:
>
> - Display all kinds of DICOM files (including multi-frame, enhanced, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, MIME Encapsulation, SR, PR, KOS, AU, RT and ECG)
> - Viewer for common image formats (TIFF, BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, RAS, HDR, and PNM)
> - Image manipulation (pan, zoom, windowing, presets, rotation, flip, scroll, crosshair, filtering...)
> - Layouts for comparing series or studies
> - Advanced series synchronization options
> - Display Presentation States (GSPS) and Key Object Selection
> - Create key images (Key Object Selection object) by selection
> - Support of Modality LUTs, VOI LUTs, and Presentation LUTs (even non-linear)
> - Support of several screens with different calibration, support of HiDPI (High Dots Per Inch) monitors, full-screen mode
> - Multiplanar reconstructions and Maximum Intensity Projection
> - Display Structured Reports
> - Display and search into all DICOM attributes
> - Display cross-lines
> - Measurement and annotation tools
> - Region statistics of pixels (Min, Max, Mean, StDev, Skewness, Kurtosis, Entropy)
> - Histogram of modality values
> - SUV measurement
> - Save measurements and annotations in DICOM PR or XML file
> - Import CD/DVD and local DICOM files
> - Export DICOM with several options (DICOMDIR, ZIP, ISO image file with Weasis, TIFF, JPEG, PNG...)
> - Magnifier glass
> - Native and DICOM printing
> - Read DICOM image containing float or double data (Parametric Map)
> - DICOM ECG Viewer

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me as others didn't support JPEG2000 compressed files.

Comment: To export JPEG, use File > Export > DICOM, then choose "JPEG" in the dropdown there. "Selected view to clipboard" does not export the full-resolution image.

Comment: weasis is amazing

Comment: There is an undeclared dependency for Weasis.  It was only functional after I installed `pixelmed-apps` package, which included multiple dependencies.  Before that, Weasis could not detect any viewable images.  This may be true of other applications also.

Answer (score 14):

### [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)

You can also just use GIMP (*GNU Image Manipulation Program*) to [open DICOM images](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-introduction-history-2-10.html).

Comment: GIMP is mighty <3

Comment: Didn't work for me with gimp 2.10

Comment: However, it loads only the first frame of a multi-frame image

Comment: Advanced Raidology CDs that  have `autorun.inf` executing a `pbcdview.exe` also provided a subdirectory whose files have been identified as 'DICOM medical image file` by `file` utility tool.

None of the above works for this one.

Comment: There is [an issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/313) related to DICOM files on GIMP

Answer (score 3):

### [Aliza](https://www.aliza-dicom-viewer.com) (on [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.AlizaMedicalImaging.AlizaMS))

It has free version and non-free version. The source code of the free version is hosted in [GitHub](https://github.com/AlizaMedicalImaging/AlizaMS).

You can also check this link to find out more options, [16 Best Free Linux Medical Imaging Software](https://www.linuxlinks.com/medicalimaging/)

[image: 16 Best Free Linux Medical Imaging Software]

Comment: This list may be useful, but I failed to find a rationale for the ratings.

Answer (score 2):

On a whim I tried the ImageMagick `convert` command, and it worked like a charm:

```bash
convert IMG00001.dcm IMG00001.png
```

or to jpeg:

```bash
convert IMG00001.dcm IMG00001.jpg
```

I have not played around with resizing or any ImageMagick filters, as the simple `convert` did all I wanted it to.

Granted, this may not be useful as other dicom viewers (answered by others here) have different tools available for examining or measuring things on the images. If you only want to open and look at the raw photos - eg, of a personal exam - then a simple batch convert may work for you:

```bash
find path/to/folder -type f -name "*.dcm" -exec convert {} {}.png \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Amide may help:

```
sudo apt install amide
amide
```

Answer (score 0):

### [InVesalius](https://www.cti.gov.br/invesalius/) ([on GitGub](https://github.com/invesalius/invesalius3) & [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/br.gov.cti.invesalius))

3D medical imaging reconstruction software.

> InVesalius generates 3D medical imaging reconstructions based on a sequence of 2D DICOM files acquired with CT or MRI equipments. InVesalius is internationalized (currently available in English, Portuguese, French, German, Spanish, Catalan, Romanian, Korean, Italian and Czech), multi-platform (GNU Linux, Windows and MacOS) and provides several tools:
>
> - DICOM-support including: (a) ACR-NEMA version 1 and 2; (b) DICOM version 3.0 (including various encodings of JPEG -lossless and lossy-, RLE)
> - Support to Analyze files
> - Support to BMP, PNG, JPEG and TIF files
> - Image manipulation facilities (zoom, pan, rotation, brightness/contrast, etc)
> - Segmentation based on 2D slices
> - Pre-defined threshold ranges according to tissue of interest
> - Segmentation based on watershed
> - Edition tools (similar to Paint Brush) based on 2D slices
> - Linear and angular measurement tool
> - Volume reorientation tool
> - 3D surface creation
> - 3D surface volume measurement
> - 3D surface connectivity tools
> - 3D surface exportation (including: binary and ASCII STL, PLY, OBJ, VRML, Inventor)
> - High-quality volume rendering projection
> - Pre-defined volume rendering presets
> - Volume rendering crop plane
> - Picture exportation (including: BMP, TIFF, JPG, PostScript, POV-Ray)

---

**[pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/)**, to manipulate DICOM files with Python.

> pydicom is a pure Python package for working with DICOM files. It lets you read, modify and write DICOM data in an easy "pythonic" way.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't open compressed Dicom files with either aeskulap, dicombrowser, amide, dicomscope, or ginkgocadx. I was successful with Aliza MS (https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.AlizaMedicalImaging.AlizaMS), flatpak version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1324581)