# For each file in a directory, pass it as an argument to an image viewer

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, image-processing, batch

I have a directory with a bunch of `.dcm` files (they are medical scans) that looks like this:

```
J6071c1.dcm  J6071d7.dcm  J6071ed.dcm  J607203.dcm  J607219.dcm  J60722f.dcm
J6071c2.dcm  J6071d8.dcm  J6071ee.dcm  J607204.dcm  J60721a.dcm  J607230.dcm
J6071c3.dcm  J6071d9.dcm  J6071ef.dcm  J607205.dcm  J60721b.dcm  J607231.dcm
J6071c4.dcm  J6071da.dcm  J6071f0.dcm  J607206.dcm  J60721c.dcm  J607232.dcm
J6071c5.dcm  J6071db.dcm  J6071f1.dcm  J607207.dcm  J60721d.dcm  J607233.dcm
J6071c6.dcm  J6071dc.dcm  J6071f2.dcm  J607208.dcm  J60721e.dcm  J607234.dcm
J6071c7.dcm  J6071dd.dcm  J6071f3.dcm  J607209.dcm  J60721f.dcm  J607235.dcm
J6071c8.dcm  J6071de.dcm  J6071f4.dcm  J60720a.dcm  J607220.dcm  J607236.dcm
J6071c9.dcm  J6071df.dcm  J6071f5.dcm  J60720b.dcm  J607221.dcm  J607237.dcm
J6071ca.dcm  J6071e0.dcm  J6071f6.dcm  J60720c.dcm  J607222.dcm  J607238.dcm
J6071cb.dcm  J6071e1.dcm  J6071f7.dcm  J60720d.dcm  J607223.dcm  J607239.dcm
J6071cc.dcm  J6071e2.dcm  J6071f8.dcm  J60720e.dcm  J607224.dcm  J60723a.dcm
J6071cd.dcm  J6071e3.dcm  J6071f9.dcm  J60720f.dcm  J607225.dcm  J60723b.dcm
J6071ce.dcm  J6071e4.dcm  J6071fa.dcm  J607210.dcm  J607226.dcm  J60723c.dcm
J6071cf.dcm  J6071e5.dcm  J6071fb.dcm  J607211.dcm  J607227.dcm  J60723d.dcm
J6071d0.dcm  J6071e6.dcm  J6071fc.dcm  J607212.dcm  J607228.dcm  J60723e.dcm
J6071d1.dcm  J6071e7.dcm  J6071fd.dcm  J607213.dcm  J607229.dcm  J60723f.dcm
J6071d2.dcm  J6071e8.dcm  J6071fe.dcm  J607214.dcm  J60722a.dcm  J607240.dcm
J6071d3.dcm  J6071e9.dcm  J6071ff.dcm  J607215.dcm  J60722b.dcm  J607241.dcm
J6071d4.dcm  J6071ea.dcm  J607200.dcm  J607216.dcm  J60722c.dcm  J607242.dcm
J6071d5.dcm  J6071eb.dcm  J607201.dcm  J607217.dcm  J60722d.dcm
J6071d6.dcm  J6071ec.dcm  J607202.dcm  J607218.dcm  J60722e.dcm
```

I followed [this information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909692/is-there-a-way-to-open-dicom-files) and installed `dicomscope` in order to view the images.

Typing `dicomscope J6071c1.dcm` opens that particular image.

In the GUI for `dicomscope` itself, there seems to be no way to open multiple files and view them (sort of like as in a slideshow).

I want to type something like `dicomscope *.dcm` in order to open every file in the directory, but it doesn't work.

Similarly, `ls | dicomscope` doesn't work.

In both cases, `dicomscope` starts but only displays a black screen in the image viewer.

Would a kindly bash/zsh wizard please help me out? Cheers.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want ~100 instances of the application, each showing one image?

Comment: What happens if you run `dicomscope J6071c1.dcm J6071c2.dcm` ?

Comment: `for dcm in *.dcm; do dimscope "$dcm"; done`

Comment: @SebastianStark Using aeskulap actually worked for me. I suppose this should be the answer, even though now my title for this question is incorrect. It should really have been "How do I view multiple DICOM files?"

Comment: @M.Becerra The application runs, the GUI opens and displays a completely black image in the viewer.

Comment: @danzel I want to see all the DICOM files displayed in something like an image viewer, where I can scroll through the images (or at least easily navigate them, instead of having to run `dicomsope image1.dcm` and `dicomscope image2.dcm`, etc., to see the images separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried aeskulap (http://aeskulap.nongnu.org/) from the link you posted, instead of dcomscope? Install it using

```
sudo apt install aeskulap
```

Then simply run it like this

```
aeskulap *.dcm
```

and it will let you scroll through the images.

Answer (score 4):

Open one after the other:
(To stop, switch to terminal and press `Ctrl+c`)

```
for f in *.dcm; do dicomscope "$f"; done
```

Open all together (will only work, if `dicomscope` allows simultaneous instances):
(Maybe try first with fewer files)

```
for f in *.dcm; do dicomscope "$f" & done
```

Comment: I think that your answer is technically correct, but, most likely due to some sort of bug on `dicomscope`'s part, only a black image is displayed for the first solution, while my system hangs for the second.

Comment: However, it is a useful reference for when I need to do something similar to this in the future! :) Thanks!