# Can digikam view DICOM (x-rey images) files

Tags: digikam

Is there a plugin or extension or something similar so that digikam can view DICOM pictures? I know there are several viewers available and I currently use Aeskulap but it would be nice to have these pictures in digikam.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/909702/66509

Comment: I know this question but doesn't help in viewing such images with digikam